# Splitting the string based on alphabet followed by numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I try to split the string A1B22C333 to get the array `[0] => A1` , `[1] => B22`, `[2] => C333`. This is my failed attempt:

```
$mystring = "A1B22C333";
$pattern  = "[\w\d+]";
$arr = preg_split("/".$pattern."/", $mystring);
print_r($arr);
```

But i get:
`Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => )`

Comment: Can someone help me rename the title of the question to prevent duplicates?
EDIT: Thx rock321957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
(?<!^)(?=\D)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF3pB9/2)

The `(?<!^)(?=\D)` matches location not at the start of the string and before a non-digit character.

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/sFBGqQ):

```
$mystring = "A1B22C333";
$pattern  = '~(?<!^)(?=\D)~';
$arr = preg_split($pattern, $mystring);
print_r($arr);
// => Array( [0] => A1    [1] => B22    [2] => C333 )
```

You can also shorten the regex to a mere `'~(?=\D)~'` (position before a non-digit) if you use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` ([demo](https://ideone.com/QZJPju)):

```
$pattern  = '~(?=\D)~';
$arr = preg_split($pattern, $mystring, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I never saw the `~` char in a regex before, can someone explain for what it is used?

Comment: A `~` is a regex delimiter, same as `/`, but as `/` is often used in the pattern (and then all `/` must be escaped in the pattern), a `~` is a more convenient delimiter to use.

Comment: Thats a good tipp, thank you @Wiktor, i will only use `~` now in the future.

Comment: @EdwardBlack: Just do not forget to escape literal `~` inside the pattern then (*everywhere* inside the pattern). Also, your `[\w\d+]` did not work because it matches 1 alphanumeric or a literal `+` symbol, and when splitting a string that only consists of these characters, you get an expected array of multiple empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `preg_split` use `preg_match_all` along with following regex

```
([a-zA-Z]\d+)
```

So your code looks like as

```
preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z]\d+)/","A1B22C333",$m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A1
    [1] => B22
    [2] => C333
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use preg_match_all.

```
preg_match_all("/([A-Z]\d+)/", "A1B22C333", $output_array);
```

click on preg_match_all
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fnj